# Laplacian spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, spectral-theory, semigroup-of-operators

I have found (in lecture notes) a method to calculate the spectrum of the operator
$$
A:D(A)\subset L^2([0,\pi])\longrightarrow L^2([0,\pi])\text{, such that}
$$
$$
Au=\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial^2x^2}\, \text{, with the domain } D(A)=\{u\in H^{2}([0,\pi]):u(0)=u(\pi)=0\}.
$$
The method is: take $v\in L^2([0,\pi])$. we will show that for $\lambda\neq n^2$($n\in\mathbb{N}^{*})$, the system
$$(1)\begin{cases}
\lambda u(x)-u''(x)=v(x), \text{ for } 0<x<\pi\\
u(0)=u(\pi)=0
\end{cases}
$$
admits a unique solution $u\in D(A)$. Indeed, denoting by 
$$
v(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}v_{n}\sin(nx),\, \text{ for }x\in[0,\pi],
$$
the Fourier series of $v$. We seek a solution $u$ such that
$$
u(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}u_{n}\sin(nx),\, \text{ for }x\in[0,\pi].
$$
To satisfy the system $(1)$, we must have
$$
(\lambda+n^2)u_{n}=v_{n},\, \text{ for }n\geq 1.
$$
So, for $\lambda\neq -n^2$ the system $(1)$ admits a unique solution given by
$$
u(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\dfrac{v_{n}}{\lambda+n^2}\sin(nx),\, \text{ for }x\in[0,\pi].$$
Thus $\sigma(A)=\{-n^2:\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

**My question is: how can I calculate the spectrum of the following operator
$$
A:D(A)\subset L^1([0,\pi])\longrightarrow L^1([0,\pi])\text{, such that}
$$
$$
Au=\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial^2x^2}\, \text{, with the domain } D(A)=\{u\in W^{2,1}([0,\pi]):u(0)=u(\pi)=0\}?
$$
Thank you in advance**